# Match Serial Number to a given computername

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want my rename my computer to a specific computername.
The script should identify my serial number and match the given computername.

For example I have a list of serial numbers with a specific computername.

```
txt.file

$COMPUTERNAME01;$SERIALNUMBER
$COMPUTERNAME02;$SERIALNUMBER
$COMPUTERNAME03;$SERIALNUMBER
$COMPUTERNAME04;$SERIALNUMBER
```

```
rename.ps1

$serial = gwmi win32_bios | select -ExpandProperty Serialnumber
$pos = $name.IndexOf(";")
$leftPart = $name.Substring(0,$pos)
$rightPart = $name.Substring($pos +1)
$newName = $leftPart WHERE $righPart eq $serial
rename-computer -newname $newName
```

I guess the error is at the WHERE command but I really dont know what to put in it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text file you have is a csv file with `;` as delimiter without headers.

In that case you could do:

```
$names   = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\PcNamesAndNumbers.csv' -Header 'ComputerName','BiosSerial' -Delimiter ';'
$serial  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Serialnumber
$newName = $names | Where-Object { $_.BiosSerial -eq $serial } | Select-Object -First 1

if ($newName) {
    Rename-Computer -NewName $newName.ComputerName -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Make sure you keep the `-WhatIf` switch in place until you are absolutely sure by reading whatever is written in the console is correct. Remove that switch to actually perform the rename.